# SWI-Prolog: Call 3=2+1 -> Fail: 3=2+1

Tags: prolog

I'm working on something in Prolog and I wanted to check, at some point in my proogram, if some variable1 equals variable 2 + 1 (var1=var2+1). It said false. Variable1 is equal to 3 in my case, and var2 is equal to 2. It doesn't register as true and I can't understand why. I tried to 'trace' it, but still can't understand what the problem is, it just fails.

Comment: Because `2+1` is just `2+1`, not `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog `2+1` is just `2+1`, or more canonical `+(2,1)`. After all, it is only because some people see `+` as addition that `2+1` is *equivalent* to `3`.

You can use [**`is/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/search?for=is%2F2) to *evaluate* an arithmetic expression, for example:

```
?- X is 2+1.
X = 3.

?- 3 is 2+1.
true.
```

You can also [**`=:=/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3A%3D)/2) to check if the two operands are equivalent if these are evaluated arithmetically:

```
?- 3 =:= 2+1.
true.
?- 4 =:= 2+1.
false.
```